Загрузка файлов, предварительный ответ от php до завершения. (Общение со скриптом в процессе)
Каким образом возможно выполнить следующую задачу.
Отправляем файл на загрузку, файл загружается, необходимо отдать от php сообщение пользователю. При этом, скрипт не завершает свою работу, поскольку он по завершению загрузки начинает обрабатывать файл.
А по завершению, отдаю данные таким образом
die(json_encode(['js' =>"e.dataset.str = 'Файл  загружен'"]));

В процессе загрузки, возможно общаться со скриптом php?
Как файл загружен, необходимо отдать сообщение, далее скрипт продолжает работать. Именно сообщение от php, а не условие в Javascript.
Как вариант, создать txt файл с текстом и его подгрузить при загрузке в 100%. Прочитать что за сообщение...

На один запрос ожидается один ответ. Что бы можно было делать N запросов и M ответов, посмотрите в сторону сокета или SSE

На чистом РНР никак, только первые две части - после загрузки вывести сообщение и продолжить работу. То что вам нужно делается на JS. Сначала аякс запросом загружаем файл. по завершении обработки РНР файл пишет об этом в бд. фронт периодически опрашивает скрипт на сервере, который проверяет запись в БД. Ну или сокеты.
